# В чём разница в смысле между «сколько всего» и «сколько»?

Tags: значение-слов

> Сейчас ты сидишь, сочиняешь пластинку и думаешь, **сколько всего** тебе ещё надо успеть за день.
>
> Сейчас ты сидишь, сочиняешь пластинку и думаешь, **сколько** тебе ещё надо успеть за день.

Интересно, чем отличается по смыслу «сколько всего» от «сколько»?

Comment: Сочинять пластинку, — это как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Сколько всего** - здесь: как много *разных* дел.

**Сколько** - насколько много *чего-либо* (возможно, чего-то одного - с этим здесь неопределённость) в количественном отношении, напр. *сколько ещё страниц прочитать*.

Answer (score 1):

**Сколько всего  надо успеть.**

**Из словаря:**

ВСЕГО. I. к Весь и Всё. **II.** местоим. нареч. **Итого, в общем**. В. израсходовано сто рублей.  **III.** **частица**. Указывает на ограниченное количество кого-, чего-л.; не больше чем; только.  До экзамена осталось в. два дня.

<**Всего лишь; всего только; всего-то**, в зн. частицы. Только это и больше ничего. Это была всего лишь шутка. Всего только год живу я в Москве. Всего-то один час остался до отъезда. **Всего-навсего**, в зн. частицы. Только, лишь. Нас всего-навсего двое. **Всего ничего**, в зн. нареч. Почти ничего, очень мало. Денег осталось всего ничего.

Сколько всего ― это ***как много всего***. То есть это сочетание имеет значение частицы со значением "очень много". Интересно, что в словаре такое значение не обозначено, а частица ***всего лишь*** ― это очень мало. Значит, наречие ***всего*** усиливает значение того слова, с которым сочетается.

Итак:

Сейчас ты сидишь, сочиняешь пластинку и думаешь, сколько всего тебе ещё надо успеть за день. **Здесь прямое значение** ― сколько именно.

Сейчас ты сидишь, сочиняешь пластинку и думаешь, сколько тебе ещё надо успеть за день. **Здесь эмоциональная оценка** ― как много!

Comment: Jasmin, Мне кажется, Вы решили не обращать внимания на стилистические неточности (сочиняешь пластинку), но  я думаю, что если Вы в ответе приводите предложение целиком, то ничего в нем нельзя оставлять без внимания.

Comment: Какая тут неточность? Высказывание разговорного стиля, в котором применен художественный прием метонимия (перенос по смежности с части предмета на предмет): сочиняешь песни для пластинки - сочиняешь пластинку.  Когда я привожу реальные тексты из Нацкорпуса - это живая речь, и делаю я это для того, чтобы обосновать свое мнение (словарь, тексты). Вероятно, я  зря этим занимаюсь, так как голосуют и принимают ответ-мнение, ничем не подкрепленный, а на мои "упражнения" никто даже внимания не обращает. Или это действительно не нужно, или это личное отношение  участников не к фавориту форума

Comment: Jasmin, Не пойму, прочем здесь Нацкорпус в данном случае. Там нет "сочинить + пластинка". А в интернете есть считанное число мест где "сочиняют пластинки", и похоже, что все эти тексты - перевод.

Comment: У меня такое впечатление, что если и есть активный фаворит в данный момент на форуме, то это Jasmin. Старые "авторитеты" редко подают голос, а постоянные авторы вопросов даже иногда прямо пишут, что хотят узнать Ваше, Jasmin, мнение. Ну а спорить ведь не возбраняется? Так рождается истина :)

Comment: 1)  Я действительно не всегда обращаю внимание на возможные неточности, а просто цитирую высказывание как пример БЕЗ ИЗМЕНЕНИЯ. В данном случае "стиль" был неважен, речь шла о значении слова.. 2) Ответы здесь по смыслу практически одинаковы (не было никакого спора), но разница в оценке существенная.   Я обычно не просматриваю старые ответы и голосование, а здесь (после вашего комментария) обратила внимание. И фавориты  -  это не "авторитеты", это  те, кого любят (я об этом).